# Joining subselects with a calendar table to fill in days with missing data

Tags: mysql, join, calendar, timestamp

I have a table with device start/stop times and a device identifier. What I'm ultimately trying to achieve is a result that groups both total daily runtime and runtime during a given period (in seconds) for each day within the specified range.

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
time        ADduration  PPduration
2014-07-18  0.66        0.66
2014-07-20  0.53        0.30
```

A portion of the database:

```
CREATE TABLE ac 
(
 startTime datetime, 
 endTime datetime,
 status tinyint(4), 
 device varchar(5)
);

INSERT INTO ac
(startTime, endTime, status, device)
VALUES
('2014-07-18 05:00:00','2014-07-18 05:04:00',1,'PWR6'),
('2014-07-18 05:54:00','2014-07-18 06:06:00',1,'PWR8'),
('2014-07-18 06:57:00','2014-07-18 07:11:00',1,'PWR8'),
('2014-07-18 10:01:00','2014-07-18 10:15:00',1,'PWR8'),
('2014-07-20 22:37:00','2014-07-20 22:55:00',1,'PWR8'),
('2014-07-20 22:38:00','2014-07-20 22:40:00',1,'PWR6'),
('2014-07-20 23:07:00','2014-07-20 23:12:00',1,'PWR6'),
('2014-07-20 23:12:00','2014-07-20 23:26:00',1,'PWR8'),
('2014-07-20 23:39:00','2014-07-20 23:44:00',1,'PWR6');
```

I've read up on the 'calendar table' trick, so I also have a calendar table within my database.

```
CREATE TABLE calendar (calendar_date date);

INSERT INTO calendar (calendar_date)
VALUES
('2014-07-18'),
('2014-07-19'),
('2014-07-20');
```

I've constructed several queries that *almost* achieve what I'm looking for, but I can't seem to wrap them all together.

This query can get me the calendar joined with my data table to make sure dates without any data are still represented in my results, but I think I need a subselection involved to make sure only a single device is included.

```
SELECT calendar.calendar_date as DATE, IFNULL(truncate(sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, startTime,            stopTime))/60/60,2),0) AS duration
FROM `ac` RIGHT JOIN calendar ON (DATE(startTime) = calendar.calendar_date)
WHERE calendar.calendar_date BETWEEN '2014-07-18' AND '2014-07-20'
GROUP BY DATE
```

Results in:

```
DATE, duration
2014-07-18, 0.73
2014-07-19, 0.00
2014-07-20, 0.73
```

This is as close as I've come, but it doesn't include all the days within the range specified, and when the time selector in the second selection restricts the results to 0 rows, the larger selection fails to include a date for the given piece of data.

```
SELECT AllDay.time, AllDay.duration as ADduration, PP.duration as PPduration 
FROM (
    SELECT date(startTime) as time, truncate(sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, startTime, stopTime))/60/60,2) as duration 
    FROM `ac` 
    WHERE startTime BETWEEN '2014-07-18' AND '2014-07-22' 
    AND device = 'PWR8' 
    GROUP BY date(startTime)) AllDay 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT date(startTime) as time, truncate(sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, startTime, stopTime))/60/60,2) as duration 
    FROM `ac` 
    WHERE startTime BETWEEN '2014-07-18' AND '2014-07-22' 
    AND time(startTime) BETWEEN '03:00:00' AND '23:00:00' 
    AND device = 'PWR8' 
    GROUP BY date(startTime)) PP 
ON AllDay.time = PP.time
```

Results in:

```
time, ADduration, PPduration
2014-07-18, 0.66, 0.66
2014-07-20, 0.53, 0.30
```